# How to refactor code handling IO (Maybe a) to use monad transformer?

Tags: haskell, monads, monad-transformers

I'm trying to understand monad transformers. I have a code like this (that doesn't work):

```hs
import System.IO (hFlush, stdout)
import Text.Read (readMaybe)

add1 :: Int -> IO (Maybe Int)
add1 x = return $ Just (x + 1)

readNumber :: IO (Maybe Int)
readNumber = do
  putStr "Say a number: "
  hFlush stdout
  inp <- getLine
  return $ (readMaybe inp :: Maybe Int)

main :: IO ()
main = do
  x <- readNumber >>= add1
  print x
```

It throws

```
Couldn't match type ‘Int’ with ‘Maybe Int’
      Expected: Maybe Int -> IO (Maybe Int)
        Actual: Int -> IO (Maybe Int)
```

I figured out that I can make it work by introducing

```hs
(>>>=) :: IO (Maybe a) -> (a -> IO (Maybe b)) -> IO (Maybe b)
x >>>= f =
  x >>= go f
  where
    go _ Nothing = return Nothing
    go f (Just x) = f x
```

and using it instead of `>>=`. This is strikingly similar to a [monad transformer](https://www.fpcomplete.com/haskell/tutorial/monad-transformers/), but I can't get my head around how exactly I should refactor this code to use it.

You may wonder "why does `add1` return IO?" Let's say that it can be something more complicated that uses IO.

I'm looking to understand it better, so answers like "there is a better solution" or "it is already implemented in..." won't help. I would like to learn what I would need to change to make it work with `>>=` assuming that I want to do operations like `IO (Maybe a) -> (a -> IO (Maybe b)) -> IO (Maybe b)` that already work with my `>>>=`.

Comment: Your `>>>=` is `MaybeT`'s `>>=`. So `runMaybeT (MaybeT readNumber >>= MaybeT . add1)` ought to work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd say the most common way to use monad transformers is the mtl approach. That consists of using type classes like `MonadIO` and `MonadFail` to implement your programs and then in your `main` function use concrete transformers like `MaybeT` to instantiate the type classes and get the actual result.

For your program that can look like this:

```
import System.IO (hFlush, stdout)
import Text.Read (readMaybe)
import Control.Monad.Trans.Maybe (runMaybeT)
import Control.Monad.IO.Class (MonadIO (liftIO))
import Control.Monad (MonadFail (fail))

add1 :: Monad m => Int -> m Int
add1 x = pure (x + 1)

prompt :: String -> IO String
prompt x = do
  putStr x
  hFlush stdout
  getLine

readNumber :: (MonadIO m, MonadFail m) => m Int
readNumber = do
  inp <- liftIO (prompt "Say a number: ")
  case readMaybe inp of
    Nothing -> fail "Not a number"
    Just x -> pure x

main :: IO ()
main = do
  x <- runMaybeT (readNumber >>= add1)
  print x
```

Comment: Why is MonadFail needed there?

Comment: @Tim because it makes it possible to fail when the input is not a number. A common instance of it is `Maybe` which you also use in your question.